# Load entire workspace from R into Power BI

Tags: r, powerbi

I need to import data from R into Power BI.

I am aware that I can run an R script through the "get data" option of PowerBI that can create the dataframes i need to be imported into Power BI.

The problem with this approach is that whilst the script I use to generate the relevant dataframes takes under a minute in R, it takes too long to run in Power BI. It took half an hour before I had to cancel and look for alternative ways.

Instead I saved my workspace in R and tried to load in via Power BI:

**in R**

```
save.image(file = "M:\\PowerBI\\R Environment.RData")
```

**in Power BI**

```
load("M:\\PowerBI\\R Environment.RData")
```

but the problem is that only one dataframe shows up whereas if i load in a new R session using R studio all dataframes show up.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Save the dataframes you need as csv files and then load in Power BI with "R script" under the "get data" ribbon tab.

```
dataframe <- read.csv(csv_data, na.strings=c("", "NA"), sep=",")
```

The table named "dataframe" will show up in power bi query editor.

You can also assign other dataframes in the R script and they will also show up.

Comment: I needed to avoid the csv route because line breaks in some of the values cause the csv not to be written/read properly

Comment: I'm guessing that you are doing some manipulation to the dataframe in R and want to preserve this. How about loading the original data into power bi and then doing the manipulation in an "R script visual" in PowerBI? I have had to do this and then view the output as a PNG plot image with 
{library(gridExtra)
grid.table(dataframe)}

Comment: Yeah you're right. I could go about this approach, however my current script relies on shuffling around between many dataframes, binding them, merging them, relying on different objects in the R environment to subset data etc. When I tried to run the same script, the problem in the original post occurred. I find that by using R scripts in power BI without an environment with objects to call up will make the process difficult to replicate. The workaround i currently have is to use the openxlsx package and make excel workbooks. This seems to preserve the data correctly.